# Recognize a string containing only digits and "/" symbols in Python

Tags: python, string, symbols, digits

I have a short string, and need a way to recognize whether there are only digits and/or "/" symbols in that string. If there are alphabetical or some other symbols in the string - it is a no go. Only digits and "/" are allowed.

For example:

**a = '123456' - green light**

**b = '123//6' - green light**

c = '1m3456' - a no go

d = '1/80o0' - a no go

Comment: One way is to use a regular expression.

Comment: You can use regular expressions e.g. test `re.search('[^0-9/]', your_string) == None`

Comment: `set(your_string) <= set('0123456789/')`

Comment: Worth mentioning that the `<=` in @PeterWood's comment is roughly equivalent to the call to `issubset` in Daweo's answer - the difference is that `<=` requires both operands to be sets, whereas the argument to `issubset` can be any iterable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `set` arithmetics

```
def onlyallowed(text,allowed="/0123456789"):
    return set(text).issubset(allowed)
print(onlyallowed("123456")) # True
print(onlyallowed("123//6")) # True
print(onlyallowed("1m3456")) # False
print(onlyallowed("1/80o0")) # False
```

Explanation: convert text to set (of characters) and check if all these `character` are present in allowed. Optional `allowed` might be used to deploy another set of allowed character, for example to allow only `0`s and `1`s:

```
print(onlyallowed("01011",allowed="01"))  # True
```

If you are expecting working with very long text which have unallowed characters near begin you might elect to use `all` combined with comprehension as follows

```
def onlyallowed(text,allowed="/0123456789"):
    return all(i in allowed for i in text)
```

`all` behavior is to `return False` immediately after encountering non-truth-y value (in this case `False`, as I do membership test)

Comment: was about to say the same thing (+1) ;) <3 sets :p

Comment: Thank you all, great answers. I prefer using sets, not RE, because it is important for me to maintain efficiency and speed

Comment: I wonder what the speed difference is building the set from `allowed` instead of `text`. Might be quicker for longer text as it would fail sooner.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
strings = ['123456', '123//6', '1m3456', '1/80o0']

print([string.replace('/', '').isdigit() for string in strings])
```

Simply **removing any / characters if exist and checking if it is all digits** seems more readable to me, and also more in tune with the way you described it in english :)

Hope this helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def recognize(self):
    if re.search(r"[a-b]", self) is not None:
        print("Red Light")
    elif re.search(r"[0-9]|/", self) is not None:
        print("Green Light")

recognize(your_string)
```

If the `recognize()` function finds a letter in the string, the output will be a "Red Light", otherwise if it finds a number or a '/', the output will be a "Green Light".